# Размещение текста в таблице

Tags: html

Что нужно сделать, чтобы текст в таблице начинался не с середины, а с начала таблицы. Подскажите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте прописать `align="left"` или `"right"` (смотря с какой стороны у вас должно быть начало). Если, конечно, я правильно понял вопрос.